# script.js:1 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token . at first line- Node.ELEMENT_NODE

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, syntax-error

I'm getting `script.js:1 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token .`

at the first line of my code, the unexpected token is the period after Node -

```
var Node.ELEMENT_NODE = 1;
```

This must be something very basic - is there something you have to require to use nodetype? The program stops at this line. This is for a chrome-extension if that's relevant.

Comment: The way you're using Node assumes it is an already-existing object.  What do you get if you do console.log(Node)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `var` keyword is not used when assigning elements in objects, use:

```
Node.ELEMENT_NODE = 1;
```

If `Node` is not yet defined you will need to define it first:

```
var Node = {};
Node.ELEMENT_NODE = 1;
```

But you should know `Node` that part of the DOM API and shouldn't be overridden in global scope, see: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Node

Answer (score 1):

This is the correct syntax.

```
var Node = {
  ELEMENT_NODE:1
}
```